# Optimizing Python script for 200K row iteration over pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have written the code below to iterate over a dataframe (df_final_exheader), get the file paths and read meta-data from the corresponding images. At this point is feels slower than it needs to be but I have a hard time finding the solution (I have a non-programmer background and might lack basic knowledge).

If I am correct one of the problems is the loop over the dataframe using *.iterrows*, reading guides I *think* I need to implement vectorization but I have no clue how to pick this up. Could someone give me a slight nudge in the right direction?

```
def read_dicom_header(input_dir_im, df_final_exheader):
        i = 0
        for row,index in df_final_exheader.iterrows():
    
            ds = dicom.dcmread(os.path.join(input_dir_im,df_final_exheader.loc[row, 'path']))
            
            header_dict = {'kVp':[0x18,0x60],'uAs':[0X18,0x1153],'EI':[0x18,0x1411],'DAP':[0x18,0x115E],'REX':[0x18, 0x1405]}
            
            for key, val in header_dict.items():
    
                try:
                    df_final_exheader.loc[row, key] = ds[[hex(x) for x in val]].value
                except KeyError:
                    df_final_exheader.loc[row, key] = 'na'
            
            i+=1
            if i%500==0:
                print(row)
                        
        return df_final_exheader
```

Comment: Off-the-bat I'm pretty sure you can't vectorize this because it's calling an external library to read the file. A super-minor improvement would be to pull `header_dict` out of the loop, there's no need to keep re-defining it.

Comment: for clarification, df_final_exheader is a dataframe containing paths for 200k dicoms? each of which must be loaded and the headers checked for the specified tags? I feel like I must be misunderstanding something. My guess would be that loading the dicom with dicom.dcmread() is the bottleneck but unfortunately I dont think there is much to do about that.

Comment: If all you need is some of the meta data from the dicom file, maybe you can try including `stop_before_pixels=True` when you call [dicom.dcmread](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/dev/reference/generated/pydicom.filereader.dcmread.html#pydicom.filereader.dcmread) I agree with the other comments saying that reading a dicom is probably what's slowing you down- not the dataframe iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone, I was afraid I might be misinterpreting the relevancy of vectorization in this case. @roganjosh Fair point about the dict, I need to keep an eye on that. The script has been running all night and is about 1/3rd of the way, given your comments I'll let it run and try and tweak afterwards just to learn from it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I have misinterpreted the relevancy of vectorization in this case. The current version is running, when it's finished I'll tweak it and see to what degree improvements could have been made.

Follow up; I finally had some time to run a few variants under timeit;

- Original code; 2.654 s.
- Dict moved as suggested by @roganjosh; 2.618 s.
- Excluding pixel data as suggested by @Cammeron Riddle; 2.340 s.

To conclude; The original script ran for 48 hours, with modifications this could have been improved towards 42 hours.

Again; Thanks for the input everyone!:)